# display node owner

Tags: nodes, entities

A node has a uid field.
In a node view I would like to add a field to show the author name with his pictures.
I now added a field and using entity referencing to a view with all users where I can select the user of the node, and displaying the entity as a useraccount has the desired result.
But now I need to select the author so that's very bad, i could update the field using node_update hook but this is so ugly I'm out looking for a way how this should be done.
So basically I need to display fields form the node owner on the node as a field.

Came up with a different approach created code fields with display suite and used this for the userimage for example, works fine and no extra modules needed using this method.

```
<?php
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  $user = user_load($node->uid);
  print theme('user_picture', array('account' =>$user));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In view go to **Relationship Tab** under **Advanced** and add relationship called **Content: Author**. Now you can able to add a field of your author name and picture.

If you need to get particular node author details means you can just add **Content: Nid** under **contextual Filter**.

In Nid Relationship settings select ** Provide default value** in that select a type as **Content ID from URL**, now have the author details..

Comment: Hello, was not using views, just displaying a node.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create an [Entity Views Attachment](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva).  Checkout some quick instructions on setting this up: http://megadrupal.com/blog/show-author-profile-block-in-drupal-node.

Comment: Thx, I'll look into that, thx.